# Mostrar imágenes que están en un servidor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Tengo una aplicación MVC 5 en ASP.net pero necesito mostrar imágenes que están en un servidor  o por decirlo así en otra ruta de almacenamiento. Mi código es el siguiente, cabe aclarar que tengo un modelo fuertemente tipado.

Modelo:

```
public class AfiliacionCotizanteTapa
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BatchId { get; set; }

    public string Validador { get; set; }

    public string Verificador { get; set; }

    public string tipoFormulario { get; set; }

    public string tipoAfiliacion { get; set; }

    public int numeroFormulario { get; set; }

    public string tipoCotizante { get; set; }

    public string formaAfiliacion { get; set; }
    public string nitEmpleador { get; set; }
    public string Ips { get; set; }
    public string Ibc { get; set; }
    public string Regimen { get; set; }
    public string puntajeSisben { get; set; }
    public string Condicion { get; set; }
    public string Etnia { get; set; }
    public string Discapacidad { get; set; }
    public string Parentesco { get; set; }

    public string tipoAfiliado { get; set; }

    public string Consecutivo { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }**
```

Controlador:

```
public class AfiliacionTapaController : Controller
{
    // GET: AfiliacionTapa
    public ActionResult ControlCalidadFIR()
    {
        var Listadoin = new CalidadVerificacionFIR();
        var listadoOut = new List<AfiliacionCotizanteTapa>();
        listadoOut = Listadoin.traeErrFir();
        int posicion = 0;

        var numero = listadoOut[posicion];// objeto en la posicion 0

        return View(numero);


}
```

En la url va la ruta de la imagen que necesito que sea visualizada en la vista   pero no me muestra la imagen.

Vista:

```
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parentesco)
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tipoAfiliado)
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Consecutivo)
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
        </tr>
    <tr></tr>

</table>

<div>@Model.BatchId</div>
<div>@Model.Validador</div>
<div>@Model.Verificador</div>
<div>@Model.tipoFormulario</div>
<div>@Model.tipoAfiliacion</div>
<div>@Model.numeroFormulario</div>
<div>@Model.tipoCotizante</div>
<div>@Model.formaAfiliacion</div>
<div>@Model.nitEmpleador</div>
<div>@Model.Ips</div>
<div>@Model.Ibc</div>
<div>@Model.Regimen</div>
<div>@Model.puntajeSisben</div>
<div>@Model.Condicion</div>
<div>@Model.Etnia</div>
<div>@Model.Discapacidad</div>
<div>@Model.Parentesco</div>
<div>@Model.tipoAfiliado</div>
<div>@Model.Consecutivo</div>
<div>@Model.Url</div>
<div></div>

<asp:Image   ImageUrl="@Model.Url" />
```

¿Cómo me aconsejan que debo hacer para mostrar la imagen de mi url ya que ésta está en la ultima posición de mi lista?

La lista sí me carga ya que la llamo desde otra clase entonces si existe una url válida.

Comment: Buen día Omar, por curiosidad ¿la respuesta que te dieron fue de utilidad?¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de lograr lo que planteas, pero esta claro que si la imagen no esta dentro de la estructura del sitio web no vas a pode generar una url

Podrias crear otro action que devuelve al FileResult con al imagen, aunque hay una formas mejor, podrias enviar el browser la imagen encodeada como `base64`.

[Display image from byte array in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e6d71127-1f12-4555-879b-6a859947eafa.aspx)

observaras como utiliza el `Convert.ToBase64String()` para convertir el byte[] de la imagen en una cadena que poder poner como datos para enviar a la view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/computer.png");
    byte[] imageByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    string imageBase64Data=Convert.ToBase64String(imageByteData);
    string imageDataURL= string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageBase64Data);
    ViewBag.ImageData = imageDataURL;
    return View();
}
```

En tu caso leerias la imagen de esa ruta donde lo tienes y aplicarias la misma tecnica